# How to build a web application node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm building a web application with node.js. I have a first .js with a main link. When you click this link, I want to go a second js. This second js is a html with head and body. In the body I only show a title. 
When I click the link of first js, nothing occurs, I don't have errors but I don't see the second js.

I only executed my second js and it's right. In the html I don't have mistakes.

I would like to have examples or tutorials about I can call a js from another.

Attach my two js

Main js:

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
res.write('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">');
var linea6 = '<html>';
res.write(linea6);
var linea7 = '<head>';
res.write(linea7);
res.write('<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">');
res.write('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />');
var linea7b = '<script type="text/javascript">';
res.write(linea7b);
var linea7c = 'var a = document.getElementById("totalbicis");';
res.write(linea7c);
var linea7d = '</script>';
res.write(linea7d);
var linea7e = '<body>';
res.write(linea7e);
var linea7f = '<a id="totalbicis" href="/pruebaformulario11.js">Total Bicis</a>';
res.write(linea7f);
var linea7g = '</body>';
res.write(linea7g);
var linea7h = '</html>';
res.write(linea7h);
res.end();
});
server.listen(7000);
```

Second js

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
console.log('en 11');
res.write('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">');
res.write('<html>');
res.write('<head>');
res.write('<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">');
res.write('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />');
res.write('<script type="text/javascript">');
res.write('</script>');
res.write('</head>');
res.write('<body>');
res.write('Segunda pagina');
res.write('</body>');
res.write('</html>');
res.end();
});
server.listen(7000);
```

I need information about this.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Oh my god. Use template engine! And don't create 2 servers! Use express!

Comment: I'd suggest reading through [The Node Beginner](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) or [a similar guide](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info). An `http.Server` in Node represents the entire web application, all URL paths, from root. The callback to `http.createServer()` should inspect the [`req.method`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_method) and [`req.url`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) and decide based on them how to respond for all combinations, including errors (e.g. 404 Not Found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both applications listening on the same port.  Try reading up on how to create multi-page applications in Node. Start with tutorials about routing, take it from there.

You should never have to create more than one server for an application like this.